# You have reached your question limit?

Tags: support, post-ban

Today I was about to post a question and get

> You have reached your question limit
>   Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account
>   *

What is this about?

EDIT: (Screenshot)
[image]

Comment: I got more that 200 points in the last month, so Im confused about how to get my account clean

Comment: I'm not sure this is a dupe. The target isn't about a limit but from posting poor questions.

Comment: The message he is showing isn't matching the one in the oft-duped question.

Comment: If you have some downvoted questions which are deleted, those would still count towards a ban.  Its not about rep, but Question scores.

Comment: I acknowledge my account got into problems in the past but as I said i have earned more than 200 points, it can even be more than that. So, I see this message a lot confusing because I have post only few questions here recently. I don't see how the pointed duplicated question will help me with this.

Comment: Your questions were in a very deep hole (only 10 out of 71 got a single upvote). Now they are in a somewhat shallower hole thanks to your answers, but still a hole. You're on the right track but you'll have to keep at it to unblock your questions.

Comment: @MichaelMyers but isn't part of the message wrong/misleading? *"You have reached your question limit"* I've never gotten to see it myself but shouldn't that part only be when reaching the actual limit for questions/day/month/etc....?

Comment: @codeMagic It appears that the OP simply didn't copy the message here correctly.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, I know what you said. Ifrustrating not knowing how close I'm to get my account cleared. That could be encouraging individuals to create secondary account, not my case cause I post very few questions indeed.

Comment: @Servy I see that now in the other comments but I guess it's impossible to say. He says that's the message he got. So unless he copied from somewhere else and not what he actually got. It may be a bug and that *is* the actual message he got. Now I'm conflicted about my reopen vote. Thanks, Obama

Comment: @Servy, You can be sure that is the message I get.

Comment: @codeMagic, I have edited my question, I have posted the screeshot to prove that is the message Im getting.

Comment: @E-Bat: yeah, you left out the important part. That's why everyone was confused.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I don't get you, the message says I reached the question limits.

Comment: We were confused because your message didn't appear to match the message in the linked duplicate, but it actually does.

Comment: I still believe the "limit" part is confusing when this is the case. Also, I thought I could retract reopen votes but I guess its been awhile since I tried :(

Comment: @codeMagic Why?  Since they have a question ban their limit is 0.  They try to post a question so they pass their limit.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure, that's technically true. But it is obviously confusing (as seen here). We don't want to change things because of single instances but surely you can see how that wording is confusing being that there are limits for people who are question banned

Comment: @codeMagic I can see where it might be a problem but if you click on the link it describes what is going on.  I wonder if the OP read the link before coming here.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's a good point and it's doubtful because, really, who clicks links that seem to have additional information these days. But, even so, it seems to be worth adjusting and making more clear. Just one man's opinion

Comment: @NathanOliver, I do read the link before posting the question, that is why I posted becase the link does not say a work about question limits. And even the "limit" word does not appears there.

Comment: So 3 months go by and i cant seem to get the limit lifted. You guys say this community is fair. I think it encourages duping.

Comment: i'm also facing this same issue . I have not  posted any questions for last week but i'm getting this error message over there. please suggest me y this is happens

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Please any one can suggest me to roll back to my original account settings.

Comment: So how do you sovle this problem at last？

Answer (score -8):

There is rate-limiting on question asking; 6 questions/day, 50 questions/30 days and other limits.

See the [full Guide here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide).

Comment: He hasn't asked 6 questions today.  He hasn't even asked a single question today.

Comment: Not my case, this is my first question in days

Comment: There are other cases, I can't say which one applies to you.

Comment: From what I can tell, only 12 asked this year. Doesn't seem to match any of the criteria I see

Comment: Yep, it's unfortunately hard to figure out. He may have been question-banned but there isn't enough information. They really need to create a page a user can go to and see precisely why he was banned, even showing him the questions that got him into trouble. They should make sure all the rate limits show appropriate messages (which they may and we haven't snap-shotted them yet).

Comment: @LanceRoberts I really don't think that is necessary. If you you copy and paste `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account ` into google the first result is [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) which does a good job letting you know whats going on.

Comment: This is a standard question ban. I'm guessing the message was not posted verbatim.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, Ok, we should edit the exact message the users get into that question so they (and others) know it's their precise situation.

Comment: @MichaelMyers, actually the message I post is the only message I get.

Comment: @E-Bat: was there no link to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans? That seems like a bug.

Comment: @codeMagic, Here is my feature-request to fix this system, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258786/give-more-specific-guidance-on-question-ban-questions.